# How do I vary the amount of red or blue light with xcalib

Tags: 18.04, xorg, display, colors

```
xcalib -color <gamma> <brightness-percent> <contrast-percent>
```

Is there a tutorial or anything describing how to get varying amounts of red screen by using xcalib? I only found one setting that is way to red.

```
xcalib -green 0.1 0 1 -alter && xcalib -blue 0.1 0 1 -alter
```

Not interested in redshift, GNOME night light, or flux. Those have other issues.

Comment: I'm glad you asked this @stackinator, Flux has not been working for me since updating to 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

`xcalib -help` shows us that the options we need to adjust RGB are:

> `-red <gamma> <brightness-percent> <contrast-percent>
>     -green <gamma> <brightness-percent> <contrast-percent>
>     -blue <gamma> <brightness-percent> <contrast-percent>`

For example: `./xcalib -red 1.1 10.0 100.0`
will set red gamma to 1.1, red brightness to 10% and red contrast to 100%

Here's the [README](http://xcalib.sourceforge.net/README.html) for xcalib.

Comment: Do we need `./` in the example?

Comment: I don't think so, but i'm not on my Ubuntu system at the moment, so can not confirm. That's the example provided by `xcalib -help` (which works without `./`)